# Append data to unity class c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new with unity and c#. I have a class with subclass as below. Now I want to add new data inside the list of friends.

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public string playerName;
    public string playerId;
    public Friend[] friends;
}

[Serializable]
public class Friend
{
    public string playerName;
    public string playerId;
}
```

I want to add new friend in the friend class list.
Code I have tried till now.

```
public string AddFriends(string friendId)
    {
        PlayerData pd = playerDataDict[playerId];
        Friend friend = new Friend();
        friend.playerId = friendId;
        pd.friends.Append(friend);
        return "sdwsd";
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();
```

And then it works as you expect (almost):

```
pd.friends.Add(friend);
```

Comment: I already some friends in my `pd.friends` list. I just want to add one new member inside it. I'm learner to c# and unity. Hope you understand and help me with it.

Comment: I understand you entirely. Use a list. If you want a finitely-sized object, then use an array. If you want an expandable object (i.e. you can add more items): use a list. If you're setting "friends" elsewhere, then perhaps you can remove the `= new List<Friend>()` - I'm not really sure how Unity works with this kind of thing.